Dynamic titles for product pages and appropriate titles for all other pages
I don't know if I'm going about this the best way (hopefully I am), but I inserted the following code I found from a post on this website into my layout/theme.liquid file to make my product titles dynamic:
<title>{% if template == "product" %}{{ product.title }} | {{ shop.name }}{% endif %}</title>

Mission accomplished. It worked just as I'd hoped. However, now my products are the only pages with titles. How can I edit the code so all the pages (not just the products) have appropriate titles for SEO?

All you need is an else condition:
<title>{% if template == "product" %}{{ product.title }} | {{ shop.name }}{% else %}{{ page_title }}{% endif %}</title>

HTH

Use the default liquid object to show the titles, you can check more about this here page_title

Also, you can check the reference code from theme.liquid file of the default dawn theme from Shopify itself
Dawn theme


Okay thanks that is good to know.
